# Java synchronized deadlock?

Tags: java, scala

I'm pretty new to Java concurrency, and am getting stuck trying to code out a toy problem using locks and monitors.  The gist of the problem is that I have a class that has `get` and `put` methods, and is essentially a receptacle for threads to consume and produce to.  For the life of me I can't get the synchronization right and either end up with a deadlock or an `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

```
package concurrency

object ThreadsMain extends App {
  val syncVar = new SyncVar[Int]()

  val producer = new Thread {
    override def run(): Unit = {
      for (x <- 1 to 15) {
        syncVar.synchronized {
          if (!syncVar.isEmpty) {
            syncVar.wait()
          } else {
            syncVar.put(x)
            syncVar.notify()
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  producer.run()

  val consumer = new Thread {
    this.setDaemon(true)

    override def run(): Unit = {
      while (true) {
        syncVar.synchronized {
          if (syncVar.isEmpty) {
            syncVar.wait()
          } else {
            println(syncVar.get())
            syncVar.notify()
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  consumer.run()

  producer.join()

  consumer.join()
}

class SyncVar[T]() {
  var isEmpty: Boolean = true
  var value: Option[T] = None

  def get(): T = {
    if (isEmpty) throw new Exception("Get from empty SyncVar")
    else {
      val toReturn = value.get
      value = None
      isEmpty = true
      toReturn
    }
  }

  def put(x: T): Unit = {
    if (!isEmpty) throw new Exception("Put on non-empty SyncVar")
    else {
      value = Some(x)
      isEmpty = false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Multi-threading is some of the most difficult code there is to write.  You're new to Java?  I'd recommend not using such low level Java 1.0 constructs.  Look at the java.util.concurrency and Executor classes.  They are an improvement over the notoriously difficult base classes.

Comment: @duffymo I'm doing it purely just to understand better what the higher-level abstractions are doing under the hood.  This is just a learning exercise :)

Comment: Try calling start() instead of run() to actually start the threads.

Comment: Thank you @rustyx!  That got me unstuck.

Comment: Maybe in a toy example with only one producer and one consumer you can get away with this. But in real life wrapping your call to wait in an if instead of in a loop will cause problems. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36187086/217324

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems:

1. You should use `start` on not `run`.
2. If you are using `join` there is no point in setting the tread to be a daemon thread.
3. When you do `if ... else` in the producer, you get only the odd numbers. It should be just `if` and the rest after the `if` (Actually `while` is a better practice).

I think this way the code does what you want:

```
object ThreadsMain extends App {
  val syncVar = new SyncVar[Int]()
  val isDone = new AtomicBoolean(false)

  val producer = new Thread {
    override def run(): Unit = {
      for (x <- 1 to 15) {
        syncVar.synchronized {
          while (!syncVar.isEmpty) {
            syncVar.wait()
          }
          syncVar.put(x)
          syncVar.notify()
        }
      }
      isDone.set(true)
    }
  }

  producer.start()

  val consumer = new Thread {

    override def run(): Unit = {
      while (!isDone.get()) {
        syncVar.synchronized {
          while (syncVar.isEmpty) {
            syncVar.wait()
          }
          println(syncVar.get())
          syncVar.notify()
        }
      }
    }
  }

  consumer.start()

  producer.join()

  consumer.join()
}

class SyncVar[T]() {
  var isEmpty: Boolean = true
  var value: Option[T] = None

  def get(): T = {
    if (isEmpty) throw new Exception("Get from empty SyncVar")
    else {
      val toReturn = value.get
      value = None
      isEmpty = true
      toReturn
    }
  }

  def put(x: T): Unit = {
    if (!isEmpty) throw new Exception("Put on non-empty SyncVar")
    else {
      value = Some(x)
      isEmpty = false
    }
  }
}
```